# PANDAS divide for a given value with groupby

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to divide each 'Value' in this dataset by the Value at TIME=='1970-Q1' grouped by LOCATION.

[image]

This is how I'd implement the logic in SQL

```
WITH first_year AS (
SELECT LOCATION, Value
FROM `table`
WHERE TIME = '1970-Q1'
)

SELECT t.LOCATION, t.TIME, ((t.Value / f.Value) * 100) normValue
FROM `table` t,
      first_year f
WHERE t.LOCATION = f.LOCATION
ORDER BY LOCATION, TIME ASC
```

However, you can also assume that we can sort (ascending) the column TIME within the group and take the first value. It's always a string like 'YYYY-QX'

Expected result:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `transform`

```
df['normal'] = df.Value / df['VALUE'].where(df.TIME.str[5:] =='Q1').groupby(df['LOCATION']).transform('first')
```

Comment: If I assume the values in TIME can be sorted (it's a string, but always like 'YYYY-QX') , how can I generalize it?

Comment: @Alex try with where first

Comment: I would try with `groupby` first: `df['Value'] /= df.gropuby('LOCATION')['Value'].transform('first')`